# python, how to write an iterative function

Tags: python, iteration

I am quering a database for some paramaters which depend on a attribute called `count`!  `count` can be incremented incase the 1st query does not return anything. Here is a sample code

```
sls = {(213.243, 55.556): {}, (217.193, 55.793): {}, (213.403, 55.369): {}}

for key in sls.keys:
  if not sls[key]:
     ra, dec = key[0], key[1]
     search_from_sourcelist(sl, ra,dec)

count = 1
def search_from_sourcelist(sl, ra,dec):
  dist = count/3600.0
  sls[(ra,dec)] = sl.sources.area_search(Area=(ra,dec,dist))
  return
```

Incase i run the method `search_from_sourcelist`, and it doesnt return anything, i would like to increment `count`, and do the query again. This is to be done for all keys in sls dictionary, untill all the keys have a value!!

Comment: You don't have a function anywhere in your code that calls itself, so I'm not sure you understand what "recursive" means.

Comment: @Wooble, that is exactly what i want to do!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the most fundamental recursive function

```
def countdown(n):
    if n == 0:
        return "Blastoff"
    else:
        print "T minus %s" % n
        return countdown(n-1)
```

You will notice that countdown returns itself with a modified argument, in this case n but -1, so if you actually followed this all the way through you would get
(-> indicates a call)

```
countdown(5) -> countdown(4) -> countdown(3) -> countdown(2) -> countdown(1) -> countdown(0) #stop
```

So now you understand what a recursive function looks like you realize you never actually return a call of your own function, thus your code is not recursive

We use recursion because we want to boil a task down to its simplest form then work from there, so a good example of this would be the [mcnuggets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#McNugget_numbers) problem. So you need to tell us what you are trying to achieve and how it can be made a smaller problem (or more importantly why.) Are you sure you cannot do this iteratively? remember you don't want to blow your stack depth because python is NOT tail recursive by standard

Comment: i am aware of that fact that there is no recursion, and that s what i need help with!

Comment: perfect, i wanted an iterative method not recursion!

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is useful when you find a way to reduce the initial problem to a "smaller version of itself".

The standard example is the factorial function

```
def fac(n):
    return n * fac(n-1) if n > 1 else 1
```

Here you reduce the problem of calculating the factorial of `n` to calculating the factorial of `n-1`.

In your code there is no such "reduction". You just increment a value and start the same problem over again. Thus, I recommend you solve it iteratively.

Comment: oh yeah i actually dont need recusion! ThankS

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you need a recursive algorithm for this.

`Incase i run the method search_from_sourcelist, and it doesnt return anything, i would like to increment count, and do the query again`. This can be done with a while loop as follows:

```
for key, value in sls.iteritems():
    if not value:
        ra, dec = key[0], key[1]
        count = 1
        while not search_from_sourcelist(sls, ra, dec):
            count += 1
```

But if you really do want to do this recursively, you can do it as follows, leave a comment and I'll write it up.

Further, you should look into your `search_from_sourcelist` function, as it always returns `None`